# Is it confirmed who's Tronte Nielson’s father?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In the excellent Netflix series *Dark*, the Unknown. aka the Origin, is the son of one timeline’s version of Jonas Kahnwald with the alternate Universe’s Martha Nielsen.  He is the proximate cause of the Winden apocalypse.

Now I’m seeing multiple sources say that the Unknown is the ex-husband of Agnes Nielsen and the father of Tronte Nielsen.  This would make Jonas his own great-great-great-grandfather, and would make Martha her own great-great-grandmother.  And in terms of incest it would make Jonas the great-great-grandfather of his lover Martha, would make Hannah the great-great-great-grandmother of her husband Mikkel/Michael, and would make Katharina the great-great-grandmother of her husband Ulrich.

And indeed, the family tree engraved in Eve’s headquarters depicts the Unknown (denoted by the infinity sign) as the husband of both Agnes Nielsens and the father of both Tronte Nielsens in the two Universes, which is probably what it means to say that he’s the link between the Universes:

[image]

But my question is, apart from this family tree, is it ever explicitly confirmed in dialogue or some other way that the Unknown really is Agnes Nielsen’s ex-husband and Tronte’s father?  Or is the viewer just expected to read between the lines, like the fact that Agnes’ ex-husband was a priest, the Unknown’s line to Doris that he used to be a priest, and the Unknown’s line to Tronte that he gave him his name?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it's confirmed that the *Infinity*, *The Unknown*, son of Jonas and Martha from two different worlds is the father of Tronte.**

> The fact is that you cannot deny the quantum entanglement between the
> two worlds. The two worlds were in the cycle before everything
> ultimately ended.
>
> In those seasons we just saw one instance of the whole entanglement
> and there were multiple realities. That's why the older Jonas (before
> becoming Adam) was shocked after seeing Martha of the different world
> and he never slept with that Martha but that Martha slept with the
> younger Jonas before travelling to the past and giving the older Jonas
> the matter. By which older Jonas created the portal in the past.
>
> Because there were multiple realities that's why older Jonas existed
> to become Adam after Martha killed younger Jonas to save the child,
> *The Unknown*, *Infinity*.

[image: The relations between characters]
You must watch episode 7 from season 3 carefully. Most of the relationships were debunked there.

Comment: What scene in episode 7 confirms the Unknown being Tronte’s father?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I don't remember explicit confirmation via the show. However: The Unknown tells teen Tronte that he chose Tronte's name, The Unknown tells Doris he's a pastor (and Agnes says the same of Tronte's father), Agnes makes a comment suggestion that Tronte wasn't born out of love (suggesting rape), it's heavily implied to be the Unknown. [The Dark info site](https://darknetflix.io/en) confirms Tronte's parentage both in the family tree and the last bio entry for the Unknown (revealed in the same scene the young Unknown hugs Martha as he is revealed to be her son.

Answer (score 1):

Episode 4 of season 3 called the origin reveals Tronte's father is actually the Unknown.

We begin with a younger Tronte walking to the cave. “We are attracted to the dark like moths to the light,” the strange man tells him. He tells Tronte he knew his mother, “but that was long ago.”

“Who are you?” Tronte asks.

“I don’t have a name. I was never given one,” he says. “But back then it was me who chose what to call you.”

The older man and boy come from within the woods, surrounding Tronte. The strange man pulls out a bracelet that belonged to Agnes Nielsen and places it in Tronte’s hand.

(THE DIALOGUES IN THIS SCENE IMPLY THAT UNKNOWN WAS TRONTE'S FATHER. IN ONE OF THE SUBSEQUENT SCENES TRONTE DISCUSSES WITH JANA ABOUT UNKNOWN BEING HIS FATHER.)